# How to fetch genre of a movie using its genre ids from tmdb api in android

Tags: android, themoviedb-api

I want to display the genre of the movie using tmdb api in android, but the thing is in tmdb api first we have to find out the genre id then we can display the genre name & I'm able to display the genre id but not the genre name. Please help me

Here is the MovieFragment.java file

public class MovieFragment extends Fragment {

```
public static final String LOG_TAG = MovieFragment.class.getSimpleName();
public static final int MOVIE_LOADER = 0;
private ImageAdapter imageAdapter;


public MovieFragment() {

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Add this line in order for this fragment to handle menu events.
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater menuInflater) {
    menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_movie_list, menu);
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, menuInflater);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        updateMovie();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
    return rootView;
}

private void updateMovie() {
    FetchMoviesTask moviesTask = new FetchMoviesTask(getActivity());
    moviesTask.execute();
}

public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    updateMovie();
}

public class FetchMoviesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, JSONObject[]> {

    private final String LOG_TAG = FetchMoviesTask.class.getSimpleName();
    private final String MESSAGE = "MovieDetails";
    private final String GENRE_MESSAGE = "GenreDetails";
    private final Context mContext;

    public FetchMoviesTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    private boolean DEBUG = true;
    private ProgressDialog progress;

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        progress=new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        progress.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // URL for calling the API is needed
        final String MOVIE_BASE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie?";
        final String MOVIE_BASE_GENRE_URL = "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?";
        //final String API_KEY = getString(R.string.API_KEY);

        final String API_KEY = getString(R.string.API_KEY);
        final String OWM_APIKEY = "api_key";
        final String OWM_SORT_BY = "sort_by";

        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
        String sort_by = prefs.getString(getString(R.string.pref_movie_key), getString(R.string.pref_sort_default_value));

        //Built the uri
        Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(OWM_APIKEY, API_KEY)
                .appendQueryParameter(OWM_SORT_BY, sort_by)
                .build();

        //Built the genre url
        Uri builtGenreUri = Uri.parse(MOVIE_BASE_GENRE_URL).buildUpon()
                .appendQueryParameter(OWM_APIKEY, API_KEY)
                .build();

        String url = builtUri.toString();
        String genreUrl = builtGenreUri.toString();

        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject[] json = new JSONObject[2];

        json[0] = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
        json[1] = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(genreUrl);
        //JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        return json; //the return value will be used by onPostExecute to update UI

    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final JSONObject[] json) {

        progress.dismiss();

        //JSON objects that need to be extracted
        final String OWM_RESULT = "results";
        final String OWM_ID = "id";
        final String OWM_TITLE = "original_title";
        final String OWM_SYNOPSIS = "overview";
        final String OWM_POSTER_PATH = "poster_path";
        final String OWM_RATING = "vote_average";
        final String OWM_RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
        final String OWM_POPULARITY = "popularity";
        final String OWM_GENRE = "genre_ids";
        final String OWM_GENRES = "genres";


        List<String> poster_paths = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> genreIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<String> genreNames = new ArrayList<String>();

        JSONArray movies_list_array;
        JSONArray genres_list_array;

        if(json != null) {
            try {

                movies_list_array = json[0].getJSONArray(OWM_RESULT);
                genres_list_array = json[1].getJSONArray(OWM_GENRES);

                for (int i = 0; i < movies_list_array.length(); i++) {

                    JSONObject movie = movies_list_array.getJSONObject(i);
                    poster_paths.add(movie.getString(OWM_POSTER_PATH));

                }

                for (int j = 0; j < genres_list_array.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject genre = genres_list_array.getJSONObject(j);
                    genreIds.add(genre.getString(OWM_ID));
                    genreNames.add(genre.getString("name"));

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error parsing JSON:", e);
            }


            GridView gridview = (GridView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.movies_list_grid);
            gridview.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getActivity(), poster_paths));

            gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {

                    try {
                        JSONObject movieDetails = json[0].getJSONArray(OWM_RESULT).getJSONObject(position);
                        JSONObject genreDetails = json[1].getJSONArray(OWM_GENRES).getJSONObject(position);
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DetailActivity.class)
                                .putExtra(MESSAGE, movieDetails.toString())
                                .putExtra(GENRE_MESSAGE, genreDetails.toString());
                        startActivity(intent);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error parsing json", e);
                    }

                }
            });

        } else {

            try {
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity()).create();

                alertDialog.setTitle("Info");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Internet not available, Cross check your internet connectivity and try again");
                alertDialog.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
                alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {


                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Show Dialog: "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

And here is the DetailFragment file

public class DetailFragment extends Fragment {

```
private static final String LOG_TAG = DetailFragment.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int DETAIL_LOADER = 0;
private static final String MESSAGE = "MovieDetails";
private static final String GENRE_MESSAGE = "GenreDetails";
static final String DETAIL_URI = "URI";
private Uri mUri;

//SharedPreference sharedPreference;

final String OWM_TITLE = "original_title";
final String OWM_POSTER = "poster_path";
final String OWM_RELEASE_DATE = "release_date";
final String OWM_SYNOPSIS = "overview";
final String OWM_RATING = "vote_average";
final String OWM_ID = "id";
final String OWM_GENRE_ID = "genre_ids";
final String OWM_GENRES = "genres";
//final String API_KEY = getString(R.string.API_KEY);

public DetailFragment() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail, container, false);

    Intent intent = getActivity().getIntent();
    String jsonString = intent.getStringExtra(MESSAGE);
    String genreString = intent.getStringExtra(GENRE_MESSAGE);

    try {

        final JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        final JSONObject genreObj = new JSONObject(genreString);

        TextView movieTitle = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_title);
        movieTitle.setText(jObj.getString(OWM_TITLE));

        ImageView moviePoster = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_poster);
        String basepath = "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";
        String relativePath = jObj.getString(OWM_POSTER);

        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(basepath+relativePath).into(moviePoster);

        TextView movieRating = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_rating);
        Float rating = Float.valueOf(jObj.getString(OWM_RATING));
        movieRating.setText("Rating: " + rating + "/10");

        RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) rootView.findViewById(R.id.rating_bar);
        ratingBar.setRating(rating);

        TextView movieSynopsis = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_synopsis);
        movieSynopsis.setText(jObj.getString(OWM_SYNOPSIS));

        TextView movieReleaseDate = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.movie_release_date);
        movieReleaseDate.setText(jObj.getString(OWM_RELEASE_DATE));

        TextView movieGenres = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.genres);

        JSONArray jArray = jObj.getJSONArray(OWM_GENRE_ID);
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

        //List<String> returnList = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            String val = jArray.getString(i);
            builder.append(val + " ");
            //returnList.add(val);
            movieGenres.setText(builder.toString());
        }

        String date = (String) movieReleaseDate.getText().toString();
        try {
            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date convertedDate = formatter.parse(date);
            SimpleDateFormat postFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy MMM dd");
            String finalDate = postFormatter.format(convertedDate);
            movieReleaseDate.setText(finalDate);
            //String finalDate = formatter("YYYY MMM DD").format(convertedDate);
        } catch(ParseException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Parsing Date: ", e);
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error Parsing JSON: ", e);
    }

    return rootView;
}
```

}

So, how to solve this problem as I got stuck & not able to find any ways. So, how to fetch the genre names using tmdb api as I am using this api. Please help

Comment: put the json data that comes fom imdb in your question. You probably find that genre is another array so you need to create a String array for Genre to get it.  Visit here --- http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/  -- and go down the page a bit, you see genre json is encapsulated, so scroll a bit further down [search for]  (ArrayList<String> genre) to see how you create a string array to get it  ---

Comment: You have mutiple genreIds and expect a single Movie? That won't work. I guess there are always 2 or more movies matching the genre ids.

Answer (score 0):

You have to map your genre_ids with the Genres List you can get from here: https://developers.themoviedb.org/3/genres/get-movie-list. I hope i could help you :)
(data["results"][0]["genre_ids"] is my List of genres in this example)
Here is my Code:

```
    const genresRes = await fetch("https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/" + data["results"][0]["media_type"] + "/list?api_key=de51817441f3aca4f2ec89ee99f6c68c&language=en-US");
    const genresData = await genresRes.json();
    let genresThing = genresData["genres"]
    let genresHash = {};
    for (let i in genresThing){
        genresHash[genresThing[i]["id"]] = genresThing[i]["name"]
    }
    let genres = ""
    for (let i in data["results"][0]["genre_ids"]){
        genres += genresHash[data["results"][0]["genre_ids"][i]] + ", ";
    }
    this.dataNow.genres = genres
    console.log(this.dataNow.genres)
```